text flow across multiple columns
Relatively new to Latex. Trying to move away from WYSIWYG Desktop Publisher Scribus. I need help getting text to flow from one designated column to another. The equivalent of text-frame links in DTP.
Specifically, I want a page with 4 text boxes. From top-to-bottom, left-to-right. Let's call them 1,2,3,4. I want text to flow from 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1. I have looked and looked and come up with no solution. Suggestions ?

This is a typical task that TeX was not designed for (I'm sure somebody will prove me wrong). Maybe, if you really depend on this, it is best in the end to continue to use Scribus or some similar application?

Yes. I suspect you are right. Extensive searching has turned up nothing. Absolutely necessary for me. Printing book signatures, two-sided printing. One side recto, one side verso. Split 8.5x11 page along horizontal axis, fold into signature.

Welcome. // With some background in Scribus and a FrameMaker derivate, package flowfram is the closes you can get: https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram . It's very powerful, has some learning-curve even with Latex experience. To put it a bit black and white: a) flowfram would be great for brochures, magazines etc., b) you probably are better of with the Latex predefined documentclasses for books, articles etc. // Anyway, it's a great package created by a great mind. // Look e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flowfram

I forgot + didn't have enough space: c) publishers using DTP-templates are less systematic than you have to be with flowfram (i.e. they tweak often to neatify just this article/page)

flowfram can do automatic text flow between frames, but latex cannot change the  with of the text inside a paragraph, so flow between  frames of different widths will need supervisión and manual fixes when frames end in the middle of a paragraph, as you would do editing latex frames in a Scribus document.

Thanks for the prompt advice. No ready solution to my problem. These answers resolved my search. One of my interests in working with a text-based editor like TeX was to be able to rapidly change parameters. Decided to open Scribus .sla file with text editor. Bingo! Quick changes with a Vim macro.
